# So, introduce yourself /ˌɪn.trəˈduːs jɔːˈself/ will become /ˌɪn.trəˈduːʃɔːˈself/ right?

Tags: pronunciation

ok,

> In dialects with yod dropping, /juː/ is pronounced the same as /uː/
>   after coronal consonants (/t/, /d/, /s/, /z/, /n/, /θ/, and /l/) in
>   the same syllable, so that dew /djuː/ is pronounced the same as do
>   /duː/. In dialects with yod coalescence, /tj/, /dj/, /sj/ and /zj/ are
>   pronounced /tʃ/, /dʒ/, /ʃ/ and /ʒ/, so that the first syllable in
>   Tuesday is pronounced the same as choose [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_English).

So, **introduce yourself** `/ˌɪn.trəˈduːs jɔːˈself/` will become `/ˌɪn.trəˈduːʃɔːˈself/` right?

I got 1 example see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-VKSSd9hko) at **1:15**

I ask this question to make sure that what I thought is right!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken about the text, I think "yod dropping" is a different thing from "introduce yourself" coming out like "introduce shour-self" in real speech. It's more like it's about "dew" rhyming with "do" instead of "hue".

Comment: The video's pronunciation of "introduce yourself" sounds like /ɪnt͡ʃɹədus jɚsɛlf/.

Answer (score 1):

Yod dropping happens inside syllables, not between them.  The word 'tube' is a good example.  Standard pronunciation is 'tyoob'.  With yod dropping it's 'toob'.  With yod coalescence it's 'choob'.

In the phrase 'introduce yourself', 'duce' and 'your' are separate syllables so yod dropping doesn't apply to the y at the start of 'your'.

Yod dropping does affect the pronunciation of 'duce', and in the example I think I can hear a dropped yod.  TOOGAM's answer covers the pronunciation of 'yourself' in that example.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking what is supposed to happen, this is an example of a native speaker being a bit sloppy with one word.  The word should sound like the word "your", and should not be "yer" (rhyming with "her", or the first part of "mermaid").  In truth, as a native speaker, I didn't even notice it the first time (even after pointing it out).  I would expect that a sloppy English speaker might say "yourself" (properly), or "yerself", or "yo self".  All of those might be so close to acceptable that most other native speakers wouldn't notice, especially since she is speaking a bit quickly.  One reason is that the subtitles showed us what word to expect.  Another reason is that after the "y" sound, there are not many alternatives before the clearly spoken "self" that would make sense, so our minds simply correct what we hear.  We are expecting to hear a valid word, and so we turn the sounds into a valid word.